# JavaScript - Toggle function

Tags: javascript

Im trying to hide/show a JS function I have defined in a chrome extension.

What I have so far:
The span classes I am trying to hide are label:

```
dspan.className = "cExtension";

//Create toggle button:

function createToggleButton(){
    var toggleButton = document.createElement("button");
    toggleButton.innerHTML = "Toggle Overlay";
    toggleButton.id = "Toggle"
    var header = document.getElementById("header");
    header.appendChild(toggleButton);
    toggleExtension();
}

// find all spans and toggle display:

function toggleExtension(){
    var spans = document.getElementsByTagName('span');
    var toggle = function() {    
        for (var i = 0, l = spans.length; i < l; i++) {
            if (spans[i].getAttribute('class') == 'cExtension') 
                if (spans[i].style.display == 'none') spans[i].style.display = '';
                else spans[i].style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
    document.getElementById('Toggle').onclick = toggle;
}
```

The button shows on the header, however it is unclickable. If I change `document.getElementById('Toggle').onclick = toggle;` to `document.getElementById('Toggle').onclick = alert{"Hello");` the alert is triggered on page load on not onclick. I am trying to get this done in pure JS. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Works just fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/SdHm9/

Comment: Still can get the onclick to work. I doubt this is it, but is there anything different I need to do because this is from a Chrome extension?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `document.getElementById("Toggle").onclick = alert("Hello");` will set the onclick event to whatever the alert function returns, not the alert function itself.  So the alert function happens at page load so it can figure out what to return.  So you could do this: `document.getElementById("Toggle").onclick = function(){alert("Hello");};` and that might work.

**Edit:** Scratch everything that was here: I missed that `toggle` variable set to a function in `toggleExtension`.

I haven't tested all this so I can't guarantee that it'll all work in your specific case.

Comment: do you ever actually call the function `toggleExtension`? Cause if not then the onclick event never gets set.

Answer (score 0):

if visible is set remove it, otherwise add it

```
div.classList.toggle("visible");
```

add/remove visible, depending on test conditional, i less than 10

```
div.classList.toggle("visible", i < 10 );
```

Make sure browser support: http://caniuse.com/#feat=classlist

Answer (score -3):

Why not use jQuery?

It will do all hard job for you.

http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Cheers!